# Why a exception is not raised? If enum size is less than 100 Bytes

Tags: c, unions

The size of the union is 95 bytes, why if I try to access to 102 postion at a, a exception is not raised?, or Am I just overwriting another memory location?

```
   #include<stdio.h>

  union u{
      char a[95];
      int b;
      char *c;
    };

   union u u1;
   int main()
   {
       u1.a[102] = 'b';
       printf("%c",u1.a[102]);
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is undefined behaviour. You got unlucky and nothing happened.

Answer (score 4):

You are just writing over an out-of-bounds memory location. C does not care, but you should. Also, C does not have exceptions (at least not the sort of exceptions you mean in your question).

Comment: Yep sorry for that I was talking about a crash.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are overwriting another memory location. Nothing might happen right away, but if done in a real program you might overwrite important data and the program might crash at any time later because of this. It's not possible to say what the crash will be, or where or when it will happen.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a union you are just saying that x number of bytes can be read in different ways.

```
union u{
      char a[95];
      int b;
      char *c;
    };
```

This tells the compiler that x number of bytes can be read as a char array, integer and char pointer.  (Note also that depending on compiler switches the union may become padded with bytes to an even number of bytes).

```
union u u1;
```

when you declare the variable u1 of type union u you are declaring it as a member of the global .data segment (bear with me here).

now if you would have declared something after the union say an array:

```
char s1[100];
```

it would typically be placed after the u1 in the .data segment.

since your u1 is of size 95 when you try to write outside the union instance (the 95 bytes) you may very well be writing in the s1 array.

```
+----+ <- 0
| u1 |
+----+ <- 94
| s1 | <- u1.a[102];
+----+
```

C allows you to do such things for effiency, it doesn't do range checks on arrays, in some cases it is a blessing - it allows lots of freedom - but more often it causes trouble. In your case you are accessing somewhere in memory which may or may not be write protected.

Answer (score 0):

There are no exceptions in C .

Comment: There are. Have a look at `C99§7.6.2 Floating-point exceptions`.